# how to set width of bootstrap crausal in react

Tags: reactjs, image, slider, carousel

how to set width of bootstrap crausal in react
when we do full width the image is strech

```
  <img alt="..." />
  
    <h5>First slide label</h5>
    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
  


  <img alt="..." />
  
    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
  


  <img alt="..." />
  
    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
```